# Installation issue: "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, rpy2

I get the [following error](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/365/installation-issue-python-setuppy-egg_info) after running pip install rpy2 on a mac with OSX 10.11.2 and Python 2.7.12:

```
Collecting rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.8.2.tar.gz (186kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 3.0MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Warning: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ml/wk8739s920z0rq1_rjrb2z980000gn/T/pip-build-8TiA72/rpy2/
```

I have also tried running it with sudo:

```
Collecting rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.8.2.tar.gz (186kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 2.0MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Warning: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-FDFFDI/rpy2/
```

I have tried `pip install --upgrade setuptool` and upgrading pip to latest version but nothing seems to work.

Could you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have R installed?

Comment: I re-installed R and it works, thank you! However, I now get another error: `ImportError: No module named Logging`. Any ideas? It seems to already be up-to-date:

`pip install Logging Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Logging in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`