# ImportError: No module named Logging

Tags: python, macos

When I try to run [this script](https://github.com/hakyimlab/metaxcan), I get the following error on a mac with OSX 10.11.2 and Python 2.7.12: 
`ImportError: No module named Logging`

It seems to already be up-to-date: `pip install Logging Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Logging in /usr/local/lib/pytho‌​n2.7/site-packages`

Any ideas? This was after I fixed [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837489/installation-issue-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) by re-installing R.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `import logging` (lowercase)?

Comment: If you look at [here](https://github.com/hakyimlab/MetaXcan/blob/f9172d26ed4112db45b866583f9099c4c654405d/software/metax/Logging.py), you'll see that `Logging` is a internal module. Perhaps, you wolud like to use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). :-)

Comment: I modified the script to lowercase and I no longer get this error. Thank you so much!